# Documenting macros using Doxygen

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

```
/** @brief This is my initial struct. */
typedef struct
{
    f32   v; /**< Value. */
    int32 s; /**< Scale. */
} f32_t;

#define DECLARE_TYPE(N) \
        typedef f32_t q##N##_t; /**< This is my Q struct. */

DECLARE_TYPE(31)
DECLARE_TYPE(25)
```

The above code declares a `q31_t` and `q25_t` structs. 
I'd like to document them using Doxygen, but whatever I tried, the structs don't appear in the documentation. They are not even mentioned. Initial struct `f32_t` is the only one that is documented.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem seems to attend putting the documentation comment into the macro.  I find that if I put the doc comment with the macro *invocation* then it is reflected in the generated documentation; otherwise, it is not.  Naturally, you have to configure Doxygen to expand macros, which is not its default behavior.

For example:

```
/** @brief This is my initial struct. */
typedef struct
{
    ae_f32   v; /**< Value. */
    ae_int32 s; /**< Scale. */
} ae_f32_t;

#define DECLARE_TYPE(N) \
        typedef ae_f32_t ae_q##N##_t

DECLARE_TYPE(31); /**< @brief This is my Q31 struct */
DECLARE_TYPE(25); /**< @brief This is my Q25 struct */
```

(I have also moved the terminating semicolon out of the macro, but with the doc comment also being moved, this is a matter of style only.)

This makes some sense, since one of the things the preprocessor does is convert comments to whitespace.  It's not obvious that Doxygen must do that in a way that causes it to ignore doc comments in macros, but it is not unreasonable for it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but John's answer is somewhat incomplete. The other thing you could do here is set `MACRO_EXPANSION=YES`. This has the negative side effect of expanding *all* macros, though, so the next one to do is `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF=YES`. That limits it to only macros defined in the `PREDEFINED` section or listed in the `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED` section. So if you add your macro to that list, it would be the only one expanded.

Comment: Is that why I'm seeing the `DECLARE_TYPE`d struct listed under Functions as "DECLARE_TYPE (31)" instead of under the struct section? I added `MACRO_EXPANSION=YES`, but still seeing it listed as a function...